# MATLAB R2014b saves figure handles without asking

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Try this out.

In MATLAB R2014b, create a new function with the following code:

```
function f1 = fhandle_test(x,y)
f1 = figure;
scatter(x,y)

func = @(x) disp(x);

save('blob.mat','func')
end
```

Now call the function with some random vectors:

```
fhandle_test(rand(1,5),rand(1,5))
```

When I do this, I get this warning message

```
Warning: Figure is saved in blob.mat. Loading this file recreates and displays the figure and its
contents. Refer to  save for more information. 
> In fhandle_test at 7
```

And sure enough, the figure object is saved in the MAT file and the figure is restored when I load the file. As far as I can tell, this happens only when I save a function handle or a cell array of function handles, and only when this happens inside a function.

Now try it again, but this time change the function so the output of figure() is not assigned to a variable:

```
function fhandle_test(x,y)
figure;
scatter(x,y)

func = @(x) disp(x);

save('blob.mat','func')
end
```

This time, no warning.

What's going on here, and is there any way to prevent it, apart from deleting the figure handles before saving? I don't want the figure objects saved in the MAT file and I need the handles, my functions are returning them. I'd also prefer to avoid some ugly hack where I have to search the object space and assign the graphics objects to handles after saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because when you save an anonymous function to a file, the *workspace* of the anonymous function is *also* saved to the file. The workspace of the local function is shared with the workspace of the anonymous function, therefore any variable defined within the local function (including the figure handle) is saved to the file as well.

The rationale behind this is that it is perfectly legal for you to use a local variable within your anonymous function.

```
function myfunc(x)
    y = 2;
    func = @(x)x+y;
    save('test.mat', 'func')
end
```

In this case, you would need to store `y` within the file in order to be able to properly execute the anonymous function when it is loaded back. Unfortunately, MATLAB doesn't actually inspect the anonymous function to discern which variables are used so it just saves everything in the local function workspace (which is why you see the behavior you do).

We can verify that this is the case using the [`functions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) function to get information on your anonymous function.

```
function fhandle_test(x,y)
    f1 = figure;
    scatter(x,y)

    func = @(x) disp(x);

    % Get information on workspace of func
    F = functions(func);
    celldisp(F.workspace)

    save('blob.mat','func')
end
```

This will yield

```
ans{1} =

    struct with no fields.

ans{2} =

      f1: [1x1 Figure]
       x: 1
       y: 2
```

You can verify that the figure handle is within the anonymous function workspaces and will therefore be saved.

One potential workaround (if you really need to save an anonymous function) is to place the anonymous function within *another* function where the only local variables are the ones that you actually want to save to the file.

```
function fhandle_test(x,y)
    f = figure;
    scatter(x,y)

    otherfunc(x);
end

function otherfunc(x)
    func = @(x)disp(x);
    save('blob.mat', 'func');
end
```

Comment: Great answer. But are you sure about this? "In your case though, where you don't actually use any local variables within your anonymous function, MATLAB doesn't actually determine which local variables to include when saving the anonymous function and simply saves all of them." Try replacing `func = @(x) disp(x);` with `func = @(x) disp(y);`. I get exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: @StephenBosch Sorry that was a confusing statement. I reworded it to be clearer. MATLAB doesn't care if you use local variables or not in your anonymous function. It just knows that it's *possible* and therefore it saves all local variables regardless of whether you use them or not.